# extract less number of columns from database table as defined in @Entity class and map to same entity pojo in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My @Entity class is

```
@Entity
class Demo{

      @Id
      private int id;

      private int firstName;
      private String lastName;
      private String address;


  }
```

And the @Repositiory Interface is having method as below

```
@Query(value="select d.id,d.firstName from demo d",nativeQuery=true)
List<Demo> fetchDetails();
```

Here exception is thrown as : The field "lastName" is not present in ResultSet

Do i need to create another pojo that contain id,firstName as variable and change fetchDetails() methods to as below:

```
@Query(value="select d.id,d.firstName from demo d",nativeQuery=true)
List<New Pojo class with only 2 fields that is to be selected> fetchDetails();
```

i want the partially selected resultset to get mapped to Entity Demo automatically.
I their any way to map these two columns to the Entity Demo

Answer (score 2):

You can use Class-Based Projections that you can have a lot of constructor you need according to all fields you want to fetch

For example, here's a projection class for the Demo entity:

```
public class DemoDto {
  private int id;
  private int firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String address;

   // getters, equals and hashCode
 }

public DemoDto(String firstName) {        
         this.firstName = firstName;
      }

public DemoDto(int id, String firstName) {
         this.id = id;
         this.firstName = firstName;
      }

public DemoDto(int id, String firstName, String address) {
         this.id = id;
         this.firstName = firstName;
this.address = address;
      }
```

You must also define equals and hashCode implementations – they allow Spring Data to process projection objects in a collection.

In your repository you can add some query with JPQL Constructor like:

```
@Query(value="select new your.class.fullname.package.DemoDto(d.firstName) from Demo d")
List<DemoDto> fetchNameOnly();

@Query(value="select new your.class.fullname.package.DemoDto(d.id, d.firstName) from Demo d")
List<DemoDto> fetchIdAndNameOnly();

@Query(value="select new your.class.fullname.package.DemoDto(d.id, d.firstName, d.address) from Demo d")
List<DemoDto> fetchAllDetails();
```

Comment: This is not working.Showing query syntax error at "." I have written query as "select new com.project.demo.Demo(d.id,d.firstName) from Demo d".Also created constructor as public Demo(int id, String first name) in Demo pojo

Comment: I want to write query like this : "select id,first name from Demo" .The entity Demo is in com.project.demo package.now pls tell me how to write the correct query.I have written it like mentioned in above comment . correct me if it's wrong

Comment: It's so strange because Projection via Dto or entity constructor is my favorite method and I shaw you the right way to achieve it. So l think you've missed something in your query definition. Can you add your complete query?

Comment: @parshant this article can help you https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @Gaetan this article worked for me but setResultTransformer method is deprecated now.Is their any alternative of this method

Answer (score 1):

Projections are introduced for that exact reason. Have a look at the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

What you need is this, create an interface like this with the getter method for the fields you want in the result.

```
interface IdAndNameOnly {
  String getFirstname();
  int getId();
}
```

Modify the query like this. You do not need `@Query` for simple queries like the one you have.

```
List<IdAndNameOnly> findAll();
```

You can convert object of type `IdAndNameOnly` to your Entity type. But that doesn't make much sense. You can just get the fields which you need from the `IdAndNameOnly` object. If not what is the point of fetching fewer fields.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you need to create a custom constructor and use it [JPQL Constructor Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_05/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor).

Something like this would do the job:

```java
@Entity
class Demo{

      @Id
      private int id;

      private int firstName;
      private String lastName;
      private String address;

      public Demo() {
         // JPA needs the default constructor
      }

      public Demo(int id, String firstName) {
         this.id = id;
         this.firstName = firstName;
      }

}
```

And the usage something like this:

```java
@Query(value="select new your.class.fullname.package.Demo(d.id,d.firstName) from Demo d")
List<Demo> fetchDetails();
```